# Opencl/Gcc error vsc "fatal error: CL/cl.hpp: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, gcc, opencl

I am having trouble compiling a OpenCL code with two .cl kernel files and a .cpp file, I'm new to C++ but I know you need headers so I've downloaded many eg. OCL_SDK_LIGHT, CUDA, vcpkg OPENCL package. All bring up the same error after compiling and only after compiling [here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZroY.png). I'm using the mingw64 g++ compiling which doesn't contain the CL/cl.hpp file, I've tried adding it directly into the include file from other directories but that just brings up more errors. I have also tried compiling in and out of vsc with similar results. I have a nvidia gpu and an amd cpu. I have also added the path to the CUDA toolkit in the properties.json file in vsc.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the compiler where the `CL/cl.hpp` file is located. I usually copy the folder containing the [OpenCL headers](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper/tree/master/src/OpenCL) in the project directory. Then compile with:

```
g++ *.cpp -o Test.exe -I./OpenCL/include -L./OpenCL/lib -lOpenCL
```

Once you have the OpenCL headers, there is no need to install any SDK or CUDA. The graphics driver alone is sufficient as it contains the OpenCL Runtime.

---

For an easy start with OpenCL development, I recomment this [OpenCL-Wrapper](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper). It contains a vector addition example. The Wrapper vastly simplifies working OpenCL and entirely eliminates code overhead.

Comment: Thanks, it got rid of the CL/cl.hpp error but then i got this, i dont know if its header or code related https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1LpV.png

Comment: To use assert, you need to `#include <cassert>`.

Comment: this did not work its still showing the same error with the new #include line? the #includes i have already are iostream, fstream, CL/cl.hpp, array, and now cassert

Comment: i think i got it working, i changed the _ASSERT to assert and it compiled with errors

Comment: no it crashed after a bit of running the exe

Comment: i got rid of all the NULL errors by replacing them with zero leaving me with just this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeCIl.png not sure what this is about